# Object passed as parameter to another class, by value or reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

In C#, I know that by default, any parameters passed into a function would be by copy, that's, within the function, there is a local copy of the parameter. But, what about when an object is passed as parameter to another class?

Would a scenario like the following one be passed by reference or by value:

```
class MyClass {
   private Object localObj;

   public void SetObject(Object obj) {
      localObj = obj;
   }
}

void Main() {
   Object someTestObj = new Object();
   someTestObj.name = "My Name";
   MyClass cls = New MyClass();
   cls.SetObject(someTesetObj);
}
```

In this case, would the class variable `localObj` be having the same copy as the `someTestObj` created in the `Main` driver class? Or would the two variables be pointing to a different object instance?

Comment: "In C#, I know that by default, any parameters passed into a function would be by copy", other way around. Only struct passed to a function get copied in the scope of the function. Objects are always by reference, meaning there is only one version in memory, and every variable point toward it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objects will be passed by reference irrespective of within methods of same class or another class. Here is a modified version of same sample code to help you understand. The value will be changed to 'xyz.'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public Employee EmpObj;

        public void SetObject(Employee obj)
        {
            EmpObj = obj;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee someTestObj = new Employee();
            someTestObj.Name = "ABC";

            MyClass cls = new MyClass();
            cls.SetObject(someTestObj);

            Console.WriteLine("Changing Emp Name To xyz");
            someTestObj.Name = "xyz";

            Console.WriteLine("Accessing Assigned Emp Name");
            Console.WriteLine(cls.EmpObj.Name); 

           Console.ReadLine();
       }       
    }
 }
```

Comment: Objects aren't passed by reference. References are passed by value. That's a *big* difference, and it's important to be clear about it, IMOI.

Comment: By default Objects are passed by value not by reference, to pass object by reference we use (ref object)

Answer (score 24):

"Objects" are NEVER passed in C# -- "objects" are not values in the language. The only types in the language are primitive types, struct types, etc. and *reference types*. No "object types".

The types `Object`, `MyClass`, etc. are reference types. Their values are "references" -- pointers to objects. Objects can only be manipulated through references -- when you do `new` on them, you get a reference, the `.` operator operates on a reference; etc. There is no way to get a variable whose value "is" an object, because there are no object types.

All types, including reference types, can be passed by value or by reference. A parameter is passed by reference if it has a keyword like `ref` or `out`. The `SetObject` method's `obj` parameter (which is of a reference type) does not have such a keyword, so it is **passed by value** -- the reference is passed by value.

Comment: What? Wrong, the last line doesn't make sense. Objects are always passed by reference (period).

Comment: @States: No, "objects" are not values in C#, and cannot be "passed".

Comment: Isn't an instance of a `struct` an object? These are passed by value

Comment: Yes structs are value types objects are reference types. Simple as that. If you'd like to know more about when each is appropriate there are a great many articles on the topic out there this one from Microsoft Docs is a good example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

Answer (score 6):

I found the other examples unclear, so I did my own test which confirmed that a class instance is passed by reference and as such actions done to the class will affect the source instance.

In other words, my Increment method modifies its parameter myClass everytime its called.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Value);  // Displays 1
        Increment(myClass);
        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Value);  // Displays 2
        Increment(myClass);
        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Value);  // Displays 3           
        Increment(myClass);
        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Value);  // Displays 4
        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Increment(MyClass myClassRef)
    {
        myClassRef.Value++;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public MyClass()
    {
        Value = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `someTestObj` is a `class` and not a `struct`, the object is passed by reference, which means that both `obj` and `someTestObj` refer to the same object.  E.g. changing `name` in one will change it in the other.  However, unlike if you passed it using the [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), setting `obj = somethingElse` will not change `someTestObj`.

Answer (score 2):

An Object if passed as a value type then changes made to the members of the object inside the method are impacted outside the method also.
But if the object itself is set to another object or reinitialized then it will not be reflected outside the method. So i would say object as a whole is passed as Valuetype only but object members are still reference type.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 objc ;
    objc = new Class1();
    objc.empName = "name1";
    checkobj(objc);
    MessageBox.Show(objc.empName);  //propert value changed; but object itself did not change
}

private void checkobj (Class1 objc)
{
    objc.empName = "name 2";
    Class1 objD = new Class1();
    objD.empName ="name 3";
    objc = objD ;
    MessageBox.Show(objc.empName);  //name 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy object please refer to object cloning, because objects are passed by reference, which is good for performance by the way, object creation is expensive.

Here is article to refer to: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In general, an "object" is an instance of a class, which is an "image"/"fingerprint" of a class created in memory (via New keyword).
The variable of object type refers to this memory location, that is, it essentially contains the address in memory.
So a parameter of object type passes a reference/"link" to an object, not a copy of the whole object.